# JavaScript - Retornar dimensões de imagem

Tags: javascript, imagem, upload

## Explicação

Olá pessoal, eu estou fazendo o upload de uma imagem, com *JavaScript*, utilizando o seguinte código:

```
$('#image-background').on("change", function(e) {
    var arq = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);

    $("#mp-image-bg").attr("src", arq).css("display", "block");
});
```

Estou querendo retornar as dimensões da imagem upada, para poder manipulá-la. Dando um `console.log()` na variável `arq`, consigo somente visualizar a *URL* criada para aquela imagem, e dando outro `console.log()` no `e.target.files[0]` eu consigo algumas propriedades, como mostrado abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas a partir de nenhuma dessas propriedades consigo extrair as dimensões, largura e altura, da imagem.

## Tentativa - Possível solução

Procurando, encontrei [este artigo do stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903854/check-image-width-and-height-on-upload-with-javascript) que mostra uma solução simples, porém, o cara dá um `alert()` na largura e altura, tentei atribuir os valores à variáveis para usar no restante do meu script e não obtive um resultado satisfatório.

```
var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
$("#file").change(function (e) {
    var file, img, width, height;

    if ((file = this.files[0])) {
        img = new Image();
        img.onload = function () {
            width = this.width;
            height = this.height;
        };
        img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);
    }

    console.log(width);
});
```

Desta forma não está funcionando, gostaria de ideias de como resolver, no artigo que postei como link, há um *fiddle* que demonstra o funcionamento com `alert();`, mas quero atribuir os valores a algumas variáveis para poder manipulá-las depois.

Obrigado!

## Obs:

O `console.log()` foi posto fora do evento propositalmente, pois quero utilizar as variáveis fora deste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se lembre que o valor inicial de `width` é `null` e ele só será atribuído no evento `onload` da imagem. Perceba que o `console.log(width);` está por fora deste evento.
O ideal seria está dentro. Corrigindo:

```
var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
$("#file").change(function (e) {
    var file, img, width, height;

    if ((file = this.files[0])) {
        img = new Image();
        img.onload = function () {
            width = this.width;
            height = this.height;
            depois();
        };
        img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);
    }

    function depois(){
        console.log(width);
    }
});
```

Comment: Então, isso foi proposital, porque dentro eu sei que funciona, mas quero utilizar as variáveis fora do evento onload, é possível?

Comment: Sim vou editar....

Comment: Como eu já editei, usei uma function local.

Comment: Ok, vou testar aqui, e comento o resultado :)

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigado!

Comment: De nada, precisando só chamar!!!!....